# How can I do Python for transform data row to column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transform

I have customer dataframe and it composes of customer id and product in each time.

```
customerID  product
1           shirt style A
1           sky wing
2           sky wing
3           shirt style B
3           shirt style D
3           queen couple
4           big cup
5           small pool
5           sky wing
5           shirt style A
```

I want to transform from row to column by taking value to column name. The value in each is yes word.

```
customerID  p_shirt style A p_sky wing  p_shirt style B p_shirt style D p_queen couple  p_big cup   p_small pool
1           yes             yes
2                           yes
3                                       yes             yes             yes
4                                                                                       yes
5           yes             yes                                                              yes
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.str.get_dummies()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) to get a dummy table. Add column label prefix `p_` by [`.add_prefix()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html). Then, group by `customerID` and finally use [`.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) to replace 1 with 'yes' and 0 with empty string, as folllows:

```
(df.set_index('customerID')['product'].str.get_dummies()
   .add_prefix('p_')
   .groupby('customerID').max()
   .replace({1: 'yes', 0: ''})   
   .reset_index()
)
```

**Result:**

```
   customerID p_big cup p_queen couple p_shirt style A p_shirt style B p_shirt style D p_sky wing p_small pool
0           1                                      yes                                        yes             
1           2                                                                                 yes             
2           3                      yes                             yes             yes                        
3           4       yes                                                                                       
4           5                                      yes                                        yes          yes
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `pd.get_dummies`:

```
pd.get_dummies(df, prefix='p', columns=['product']).groupby('customerID').sum().replace({1: 'yes', 0: ''}).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   customerID p_big cup p_queen couple p_shirt style A p_shirt style B p_shirt style D p_sky wing p_small pool
0           1                                      yes                                        yes             
1           2                                                                                 yes             
2           3                      yes                             yes             yes                        
3           4       yes                                                                                       
4           5                                      yes                                        yes          yes
```

But in this case:

```
pd.get_dummies(df, prefix='p').groupby('customerID').sum().replace({1: 'yes', 0: ''}).reset_index()
```

Is enough, you don't need to specify column name here.

Comment: It's working. Thank you!!!